# My A record disappear: what can it be?

Tags: dns, dhcp

I have a little server configured to use dynamic dhcp(dhcp update automatically the hostname on dns). Works fine..but one of the A record magically disappear, while the PTR record is ok.
This is my configuration

dhcpd.conf

```
authoritative;
ddns-update-style interim;
ddns-updates on;
ddns-ttl 600;
update-static-leases on;
ddns-domainname "mydomain.example";
ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa";
ignore client-updates;
update-conflict-detection off;
include "/etc/dhcp/dhcp.mydomain.example";
ddns-hostname = pick-first-value(ddns-hostname, option host-name, binary-to-ascii(10,8, "-", leased-address));
max-lease-time 86400;
default-lease-time 14400;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.4, 192.168.0.1;
option domain-search-order code 119 = string;
option domain-search-order "mydomain.example fritz.box";
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option routers 192.168.0.1;
    option domain-search "mydomain.example";
class "ignored" {
        match if substring(hardware,1,6) = ###################;
}
pool {
        deny members of "ignored";
        range 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.252;
        }
    }
 #
 # 
 # The subnet where the server is attached
     
host samba4 {
hardware ethernet #####################;
fixed-address 192.168.0.5;
ddns-hostname "samba4";
ddns-ttl 604800;
}
zone mydomain.example.
{
primary 192.168.0.4;
key dhcp.mydomain.example;
}
zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
{
primary 192.168.0.4;
key dhcp.mydomain.example;
}
```

this is the named.conf

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.4; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    querylog yes;
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.2.0.0/24;};
    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
        allow-new-zones yes;
        dnssec-must-be-secure "mydomain.example" yes;
        dnssec-must-be-secure "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" yes;
        allow-transfer {127.0.0.1; };
        allow-recursion {127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.2.0.24; };
        version "Proot";
        tkey-gssapi-keytab "/etc/dns.keytab";
        tkey-domain "MYDOMAIN.EXAMPLE";
};
server 10.3.0.2 {
    keys {  my-tsig; };
};
key dhcp.mydomain.example {
    algorithm hmac-sha512;
    secret "################";
};
key "my-tsig" {
algorithm HMAC-SHA512;
    secret "################";
};
key "my-tsig2" {
algorithm HMAC-SHA512;
    secret "################";
};
controls {
        inet 192.168.0.4 port 953 allow { 192.168.0.4; 127.0.0.1; } keys { dhcp.mydomain.example; };
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1;  } keys { dhcp.mydomain.example; };
        };
zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};
zone "mydomain.example." IN {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/data/mydomain.example.zone";
        allow-transfer {key my-tsig2; };
    update-policy {
    grant dhcp.mydomain.example. wildcard * A TXT SRV CNAME MX DHCID;
        grant SAMBA4$@mydomain.example wildcard * A AAAA TXT SRV CNAME MX;
        grant DNS1$@mydomain.example wildcard * A AAAA TXT SRV CNAME MX;
        grant Administrator@mydomain.example wildcard * A TXT SRV CNAME MX;
 };
        key-directory "/var/named/data";
        auto-dnssec maintain;
        inline-signing yes;
    /*
     * the list of principals and what they can change is created
     * dynamically by Samba, based on the membership of the domain controllers
     * group. The provision just creates this file as an empty file.
     */
    #include "/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf.update";
    /* we need to use check-names ignore so _msdcs A records can be created */
    check-names ignore;
};
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/data/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        allow-transfer {key my-tsig2; };
    update-policy {
    grant dhcp.mydomain.example. wildcard * PTR;
        grant SAMBA4$@mydomain.example wildcard * PTR;
        grant DNS1$@mydomain.example wildcard * PTR;
        grant Administrator@mydomain.example wildcard * PTR;
    };
        auto-dnssec maintain;
        key-directory "/var/named/data";
        inline-signing yes;
};
zone "otherzone.priv." IN {
        type slave;
        masters {10.3.0.2; };
        file "/var/named/data/otherzone.priv.zone";
        key-directory "/var/named/data";
        auto-dnssec maintain;
        inline-signing yes;
        /*
         * the list of principals and what they can change is created
         * dynamically by Samba, based on the membership of the domain controllers
         * group. The provision just creates this file as an empty file.
         */
        #include "/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf.update";
        /* we need to use check-names ignore so _msdcs A records can be created */
        check-names ignore;
};
zone "0.3.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type slave;
    file "/var/named/data/0.3.10.in-addr.arpa.zone";
        masters {10.3.0.2; };
        auto-dnssec maintain;
        key-directory "/var/named/data";
        inline-signing yes;
};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

On the log nothing strange, making a grep in the named datadir, seems my A lost record is present, but dig said no

```
grep -irl disappeared.mydomain.example *
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.signed
mydomain.example.zone.jnl
mydomain.example.zone.signed
mydomain.example.zone.signed.jnl
```

dig disappeared.mydomain.example

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.26-RedHat-9.11.26-4.el8_4 <<>> disappeared.mydomain.example
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 192
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 172e90668acc5f522b6add4b617edbeb3909928cefd32999 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;disappeared.mydomain.example.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.example.       86400   IN  SOA dns1.mydomain.example. root.mydomain.example. 2020140075 60 120 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.4#53(192.168.0.4)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 31 19:09:47 CET 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

making dig -x 192.168.0.32 return the correct name.
What can it be?
I see removing the lease manually from dhcpd.leases file and restart networkmanager from client reinsert the correct A record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to be working:

```
ddns-ttl 600;
default-lease-time 14400;
```

Are a little different

I try to use same value for both

```
ddns-ttl 600;
default-lease-time 600;
```

Works but I had to recreate the leases file.